# Getting error Ambiguous use of tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using xcode 7 beta and I have found this code off a tutorial however I am using a `UIViewController` instead of `UITableViewController` for many reasons. (I don't know if this is causing this specific issue). I have gotten the `UIViewController` setup just like a typical `UITableViewController` however I am running into the error

> Ambiguous use of `'tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)`

Here's my code

```
class ShoppingViewController: UIViewController {
var toDoItems:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    var userDefaults:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    var itemListFromUserDefaults:NSMutableArray? = userDefaults.objectForKey("itemList") as? NSMutableArray

    if ((itemListFromUserDefaults) != nil){
            toDoItems = itemListFromUserDefaults!
    }

    **self**.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

as well as

```
if (segue != nil && segue!.identifier == "showDetail") {
    var selectedIndexPath:NSIndexPath = **self**.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
    var detailViewController:DetailsViewController = segue!.destinationViewController as! DetailsViewController
    detailViewController.toDoData = toDoItems.objectAtIndex(selectedIndexPath.row) as! NSDictionary

}
```

Candidates (according to XCode):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return toDoItems.count
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    let toDoItem:NSDictionary = toDoItems.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary
    cell.textLabel!.text = toDoItem.objectForKey("itemTitel") as? String

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Are you set `delegate` and `dataSource` to the `tableView`? It seems you does not conform to `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` protocols?

Comment: @Bannings How would I make it conform?

Comment: Try this:`class ShoppingViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate`

Comment: @bannings fixed another issue that had nothing to do with the current issue but i still thank you for that

Comment: @bannings see my updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a similar problem after upgrading to Xcode 7.1 beta. I wonder if this is a bug in the beta? has anyone found a solution?

UPDATE - 
so i solved this issue in my project. I had to set the IBOutlet for my tableView and then do the reloadData on that object. e.g. set IBOutlet to myItemsTableView then call self.myItemsTableView.reloadData() and that worked fine. On this project it needed myItemsTableView and reload on that rather than then generic command tableView.reloadData().

hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have initialized *tableView* properly. That fixed my same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue that I resolved by naming my View Controller something else.

There must be a view controller in SDK named DetailsViewController or DetailViewController