# Ambiguous reference to member 'tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)' Why this error?

Tags: ios, tableview, swift3

Here is my code in which the error appears:
The error is in line 3 'if let indexpath...'

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "show Detail" {
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let taakDetail : Taak = taken[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
            let controller = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailsViewController
            controller.selectedTaak = taakDetail
        }
    }
```

I can't find out what is ambiguous about this. The code to which it refers to is:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return taken.count
}
```

Comment: Show us how your variables are defined.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting error Ambiguous use of tableView(\_:numberOfRowsInSection:)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32396838/getting-error-ambiguous-use-of-tableview-numberofrowsinsection)

Comment: My IBOutlet =     `@IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not finding `tableView`, and is therefore getting thrown off, assuming you somehow meant to reference this method (which you don't, obviously).

Note, your outlet is `tableview`, not `tableView`. Properties are case sensitive.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "show Detail" {
        if let indexPath = self.tableview.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let taakDetail : Taak = taken[indexPath.row]
            let controller = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailsViewController
            controller.selectedTaak = taakDetail
        }
    }
}
```